# Export joined tables to listView, anonymous type data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, join, listbox

I joined 3 tables and i want to export the data to a ListView how do I do that? The data is a list of anonymous type, how do I get the values so I can add them to the listView?

```
var results = (from a in db.CUSTOMERs
                       join b in db.ORDERs on a.CUSTOMERID equals b.CUSTOMERID
                       join c in db.ORDERDETAILS on b.ORDERID equals c.ORDERID
                       select new
                       {
                           a.CUSTOMERID,
                           a.NAME,
                           a.ADRESA,
                           b.ORDERID,
                           b.DATA,
                           b.VALOARE,
                           c.PRODUS,
                           valoare2 = c.VALOARE,
                           c.SERIAL
                       }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to define a public class to hold the data

```
public class modelData
{
    public string CUSTOMERID { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string ADRESA { get; set; }
    public string ORDERID { get; set; }
    public string DATA { get; set; }
    public string VALOARE { get; set; }
    public string PRODUS { get; set; }
    public string VALOARE2 { get; set; }
    public string SERIAL { get; set; }
};

var results = (
    from a in db.CUSTOMERs
    join b in db.ORDERs on a.CUSTOMERID equals b.CUSTOMERID
    join c in db.ORDERDETAILS on b.ORDERID equals c.ORDERID
    select new modelData
    {
       CUSTOMERID = a.CUSTOMERID,
       NAME = a.NAME,
       ADRESA = a.ADRESA,
       ORDERID = b.ORDERID,
       DATA = b.DATA,
       VALOARE = b.VALOARE,
       PRODUS = c.PRODUS,
       VALOARE2 = c.VALOARE,
       SERIAL = c.SERIAL
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: and how do i assign each value from results to the value in the class?